# R - indirectly calling a matrix using a string

Tags: r

Example:
There is a matrix of data called VE
There is a vector of string where the first element is the string VE.
I need to indirectly call the string and be able to access data. 
For example if I need the 6th column of matrix VE then I want to do:

Vector[1][,6]

Essentially I need R to start reading those string as if they are the matrix names that are already in this page. I need this syntax to be dynamic because I am putting it in a loop.

Comment: As far as I know R doesn't have pointers. So you have to use some workaround, like lists. But it would work much better if R have pointers.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `get()`:

```
VE <- matrix(0,10,10)
vec <- c("VE","foo","bar")
get(vec[1])[,6]
```

## Edit:

This requires a global object called VE though, for automating it is probably better to keep the matrices (I assume there are more?) in a list, then you can just index:

```
matrixlist <- list(VE = matrix(0,10,10))
vec <- c("VE","foo","bar")
matrixlist[[vec[1]]][,6]
```